# Flutter how to stop auto login using firebase SMS

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When users first open the app, I want them to authenticate themselves by phone number. When they get the sms code and hit login button, the phone number and other information are sent to the server together.

However, when I press the code verification button, it automatically logs the user in without login button pressing so I cannot send data accordingly.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print("signed out - MyAppState");
      } else {
        print("signed in - MyAppState");

        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomBarScreen()));
      }
    });
```

```
try {
      _testPhoneValidation(_phoneNumberController.text);

      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: "+82" + _phoneNumberController.text.substring(1),
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
          verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
          codeSent: codeSent,
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
      );
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('failure: ${e.toString().substring(11)}'),
      ));
    }
```

this is my current code related to login with Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched how to stop auto login but didn't quite find the right answer.
So I just changed the login logic to : send info when Firebase auth state changes.

There isn't much change in the code and I think it was a dumb mistake that I made not to think about changing the logic.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print("signed out");
      } else {
        print("signed in");

        signIn();
      }
    });
```

```
Future<void> signIn() async {
    await postAppToken(
        await _getToken(),
        _packageInfo.appName,
        _packageInfo.version,
        Theme.of(context).platform.toString().substring(15),
        await _getPhoneNum())
        .then((value) {
          print("signIn");
          Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomBarScreen()));
      }
    );
  }
```

So I just added a Future to post related information to the server when user is automatically logged in. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should do nothing on " verificationCompleted" callback.
just write like this

```
verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
```

Because verificationCompleted is for automatic handling of the SMS code on Android devices.